# Xampp: composer installation issue: module openssl already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, command-line, composer-php

Xampp: composer installation issue:

> "PHP Warning:  Module 'openssl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0".

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

twice in your php.ini file. you need to remove/comment one extension

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable the extension 
from

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to be

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```